# Use other projects classpath for testing in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testing, classpath

Is there a way to configure an eclipse-java-project that way, that it uses the same class-path-configuration than an other project.

This project will contain test-classes that should work in the same environment than the 'original'.

Answer (score 1):

Make your test project depend on your product project. Then in the product project's build path properties page, make sure that all build path entries are exported. This will make them visible to the test project.

Comment: The product project is now the only 'Required Project' (I removed the others). In the product project, every entry under 'Order and Export) is checked. Was that what you meant? This doesn't work. All referenced sources are marked as missing.

Comment: You will need to provide more details for folks to be able to help you further. A good start would be the .classpath files of your product and test projects.

Comment: I will try when I have access again, but did I do, what you wanted me to do? btw: the product project contains some other projects, libs and some kind of 'con' for Junit (as I remember right).

Comment: Arrgh.... I think that's it... We use an own build process (very complex environment) and always refer all projects, that are needed (from the project use them), but none of them is exported. So my problem should be, that I have access to the exported projects, the 'first generation', but not the 2nd, which are not exported. Maybe that was not understandable, but you helped. THX!